# Django CMS get all models defined in the admin

Tags: django, django-cms

I am building a FAQ plugin that will display a list of questions and answers on my Django CMS site. I have the following model:

```
class Faq(models.Model):

    question = models.CharField(
        'question',
        blank=False,
        default="",
        help_text=u'Please type in the question',
        max_length=256,
    )

    answer = HTMLField(configuration='CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_BASIC',
                      null=True,
                      help_text=u'Please provide an answer. if you paste HTML make sure to cmd+shift+v for plain paste')

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

Which I defined in the admin:

```
class FaqAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Faq
    extra = 3

admin.site.register(Faq, FaqAdmin)
```

And I've added a few instances as content.

For now in the plugin defines 10 questions:

```
class FaqPluginModel(CMSPlugin):
    faq1 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq1+')
    faq2 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq2+')
    faq3 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq3+')
    faq4 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq4+')
    faq5 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq5+')
    faq6 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq6+')
    faq7 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq7+')
    faq8 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq8+')
    faq9 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq9+')
    faq10 = models.ForeignKey(Faq, related_name='faq10+')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.faq1.question
```

However this approach is not scalable. I am looking for a way to fetch all the models from the admin and render them in the template's html. Something along the lines of:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="box">
           --->>  {% for every faq model render this: %} <<--
                <div class="question">
                    <div class="question-title">
                        What are your supported platforms?
                    </div>
                    <div class="question-arrow">
                    </div>
                </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is , write a view and create object for the model and render to template html.

For example:

```
from models import Faq
def faq_view(request):
    faqs = Faq.objects.all()

    return render_to_response('faq.html', {'faqs': faqs})
```

Then in faq.html write a for loop and display like below.

```
<ul>
{% for faq in faqs %}
    <li><strong>{{faq.question}}</strong></li>
    <li>{{faq.answer}}</li>
{% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

I hope this will help you.